# create a dynamic SUM column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have the below query which returns, store number and its region, and the sum of the stores sales in 2016.

```
SELECT
EU.[STORE NO]                               
,EU.REGION
,SUM(SA.SALESEXVAT) AS 'STORE SALES'


FROM
[BHXSQL2014-DEV].BManalytics.dbo.EUactivestores EU

INNER JOIN
EUUKSQL01.dashboard.dbo.stocksalesaggregateweek sa 
ON  eu.[Store No]   =    sa.[branchno] 

WHERE
sa.Fiscalyear  =     2016


GROUP BY 
EU.[Store No]   
,EU.REGION
```

How would i add a 4th Column that would sum up the sales of the REGION that each store is in.

There are many to stores to each region, so this value would be the same on each ROW that has a store in the same region etc.

Hope i explained this ok ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT EU.[STORE NO], EU.REGION,
       SUM(SA.SALESEXVAT) AS STORE_SALES
       SUM(SUM(SA.SALESEXVAT)) OVER (PARTITION BY EU.REGION) as REGION_STORE_SALES
FROM [BHXSQL2014-DEV].BManalytics.dbo.EUactivestores EU INNER JOIN
      EUUKSQL01.dashboard.dbo.stocksalesaggregateweek sa 
      ON eu.[Store No] = sa.[branchno] 
WHERE sa.Fiscalyear  =     2016
GROUP BY EU.[Store No], EU.REGION ;
```

Comment: AWESOME ! i had used partition before but to group Rows with an I.D, nothing like this though, Thank You